# License Keys management

Tags: licensing

I have a desktop application that could run in trial mode. The user decides to enter a license key. I validate it and if valid the app will not run in trial mode anymore.

What should I do with the license key after this? Where should I keep it? Should I check if the license key is valid at every app start up? I want to know what should I exactly do after the user enters the license key? Thanks

Comment: Do you validate it online or offline?

Comment: I save the times of validation of all the keys and check them every time the app starts.

Comment: @AndrésRicardoTorresMartínez your commend is an answer indeed :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that, when the online validation succeeds, the server returns something that can be validated off-line - probably signed with a private key, for which the app has the public key (google public key cryptography) - this way, it can be validated locally, without the local copy having enough information to create a valid local validation token.

The local validation should have a start time and end time, and if for any reason the token is invalid, online validation should be done. If the token has recently (for a given value of recent) expired, and online validation fails, the system allows access, to give some grace time.